# Alien organisms manipulate light to make giant computers

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

Golden Age sci-fi, probably in some short story anthology. I don’t remember much from this story other than this one scene supposedly from the history of an alien species:

The aliens’ bodies are transparent, and they’re standing in some large grid. They’re able to polarize light by manipulating something inside their body, and thus using light beams across the grid they can compute (like computer). I remember there was a mention of the speed of this being exceeding fast compared to some other process.